# "git pull local branch" pulls different files than the original changes the branch containing

Tags: git

I am trying to pull the changes from master branch in another folder (folder-a) into the current folder's (folder-b) local branch (branchx).

After pulling, the changes in folder-a's branchx are different from the changes in folder-b's master branch.

The folder-a and folder-b are the clones of same repo.

[under folder-a]

-bash-4.2$ git branch

- master

-bash-4.2$ git status

On branch master

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:

(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)

(use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
    modified:   dataplane (new commits)
    modified:   controlplane (new commits)
```

[Under folder-b]

-bash-4.2$ git branch

### * master

-bash-4.2$ git pull /path/to/folder-a master

From /path/to/folder-a

- branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

Already up-to-date.

-bash-4.2$ git status

On branch master

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

---

-bash-4.2$ git pull /path/to/folder-a master:branchx

From /path/to/folder-a

- [new branch]      master     -> branchx

Already up-to-date.

-bash-4.2$ git checkout branchx

Switched to branch 'branchx'

-bash-4.2$ git branch

- branchx

  Master

-bash-4.2$ git status

On branch branchx

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Kindly, suggest me if I am wrong in pulling the changes from another folder. I want to pull the changes and finally merge into master branch of folder-a.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is a shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. You probably need to revise your knowledge about Git and rephrase your intention more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply axiac. I tried directly pulling (fetch+merge) the branch but it was rejected with an error message "not fast forward". So, I am trying to pull changes into some dummy branch first and later merging it into master branch.

Comment: *"I tried directly pulling (fetch+merge) the branch but it was rejected with an error message "not fast forward".* this is not an *error* but a *warning* in the first place. please add the complete output of `git pull` to your question.

Comment: The error message about "not fast forward" means there are divergent changes on your repo **and** on the remote repo.

Comment: I advise Git newbies to avoid `git pull` in general, but I'll state even more strongly: if you don't know *exactly* what you are doing, *never* use the colon syntax (`master:branchx`) with `git pull`. (It's not that it's especially harmful, but it has *way* too many moving parts—it's like trying to fly a jet fighter at Mach 2 as your first piloting experience.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please suggest me the best way to merge the changes from folder-a's master branch into folder-b's master branch.